# Machine learning: which algorithm fits for questions answering

Tags: machine-learning

I want to build a ml program who talks to user and get some inputs from the user.
The ml program analyze the input data(keywords) then predict the best solution.

Comment: and what is the question?

Comment: I am unable to predict the best approach (algorithm) to do this task.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

So, you are looking at an AI application which needs some sort of machine intelligence for processing natural language. 
Let us say the language of choice here is English. There are many things to be considered before building such a system.

1. Dependency parsing
2. Word Sense Disambiguation
3. Verb Sense Disambiguation
4. Coreference Resolution
5. Semantic Role Labelling
6. Universe of knowledge.

In brief you need to build all the above essential modules before you can generate your response. 
You need to decide what kind of problem you are working on? Is it an open domain or closed domain problem, meaning what is the scope of knowledge of this application. 
For example: Google now is an open domain problem which can practically take any possible input. 
But some applications pertain to a particular task like automating food orders in an app etc where the scope of questions which can be asked is limited.

Once that is decided, you need to parse your input sentence and dependency parsing is the way to go. You can use Stanford core NLP suite to achieve most of the NLP tasks which were mentioned above.

Once the input sentence is parsed and you have the subjects, objects, etc it is time to disambiguate the words in the sentence as a particular word can have different meanings.

Then disambiguate the verb meaning identifying the type of verb (like return could mean going back to a place or giving back something )

Then you need to resolve coreference resolution meaning mapping the nouns and pronouns and other entities in a given context. For example: 
My name is John. I work at ABC company.

Here I in the second sentence refers to John. 
This helps us in answering questions like where does John work. Since John was only used in the first sentence and his work was mentioned in the second sentence coreference resolution helps us map them together.

The next task at hand is semantic role labelling, which basically means labelling all the arguments in a sentence with respect to each of its verb.
For example: John killed Mary.
Here the verb is kill, John and Mary are the arguments of the verb kill. John takes the role A0 and Mary the role A1. Where the definitions of these roles for each verb are mentioned in a huge frame and argument annotation framework created by the NLP community. Here A0 means the person who killed, A1 means the person who was killed. 
Now once you have identified A0 and A1 just look into the definition of the kill frame and return A0 for killer and A1 for the victim.

Another important task at hand is to identify when your system must respond with an answer. For which you need to know if the given sentence is a declarative or assertive sentence or an interrogative sentence. You can just check that by seeing if the input sentence ends with a question mark.

Now to answer your question: 
Let us say your input to the application is:
Input 1: John killed Mary.
Clearly this is an assertive sentence so just store it and process it as mentioned above.
Now the next input is:

Input 2: Who killed Mary?

This is an interrogative sentence so you need to come up with a reply or a response.

Now find the semantic role labels of input 1 and input 2 and return the word  of input 1 which matches the argument of Who in sentence 2.
Here in this case who would be labeled as A0 and John would be labeled as A0, simply return John.

Most of the NLP modules mentioned can directly be implemented using Stanford core NLP however if you want to implement some algorithms on your own you can go through the recent publications in EMNLP, NIPS, ICML, CONLL etc to understand them better and implement the one which best suits you.

Good luck !